# Cambiar estado o valor de un botón en datatable

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

tengo una tabla en la que me gustaría cambiar de un click el estado del profesor, en activo o inactivo pero por lo que sea no funciona en datatable. Tengo el siguiente código:

PHP

```
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<?php include('session.php');  
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        echo $id;

        $data = explode("-",$_POST['id']); 
        $campo = $data[0]; // nombre del campo
        $id = $data[1]; // id del registro 
        $value = $data[2]; // valor por el cual reemplazar 


        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE teacher SET teacher_stat = '".$value."' 
WHERE teacher_id = '".$id."'" ); 
        $value = 1;
        if ($value == 1 ) { echo ("exitoso"); } else { echo ("noexitoso"); }

?>

<script>
        $(function() {

          $('#btnSi, #btnNo').on('click', function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            var activo = elem.text();
            var id = elem.val();
            alert(elem);
            var url = 'teachers_save2.php';

            var request = $.ajax({
              data: {id: id, activo:activo},
              type: "POST",
              url: url,
              dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function(text) {
              console.log(text);
              if (text == "exitoso") {
                if (activo == 'S') {
                  elem.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
                  elem.text('S');
                } else {
                  elem.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
                  elem.text('N');
                }
              }
            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
              alert("Error de petición: " + textStatus);
            });

          });

        });
        </script>

<?php if ($teacher_stat == 'Activated' ){ ?>
                                    <td data-order="<?php echo $teacher_stat    ; ?>"><button id="btnSi" value="18" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">S</button></td>
                                    <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <td data-order="<?php echo $teacher_stat; ?>"><button id="btnNo" value="19" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">N</button></td>
                                    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas `$('#btnSi, #btnNo').on()`, los botones todavía no existen porque el HTML está después, por lo que la función `on()` no llega a ejecutarse.

Haz la prueba poniendo `console.log($('#btnSi, #btnNo').length);` justo antes.

Cámbialo a esto:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSi, #btnNo', function () { /* handler */ } );
```

`document` sí existe y en cada click que se produzca en la página buscará si el elemento originador es `#btnSi` o `#btnNo`.

Comment: Ahora sí me entra en el JS pero por lo visto no modifica nada. He añadido el php de mi código... parece que consolelog no devuelve el valor

Comment: Si la modificación es lo que se produce dentro del `if (activo == 'S')`, ten en cuenta que estás comprobando contra una variable que no cambia desde su declaración. Tampoco está claro de dónde sale `$teacher_stat`. Lo siento pero tal y como está no te puedo ayudar mucho más.

Comment: Otra cosa. Tu script es vulnerable a SQLi: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL . Usa siempre _prepared SQL statements_ para evitarlo. Vale la pena.

Comment: La verdad que tengo que ponerme un poco las pilas con este tema porque sé que es vulnerable. $teacher_stat es la variable que toma el valor 'Activated' o 'Deactivated'. El botón en sí, la función que quiero es que active al profesor o lo desactive. Gracias por responder

Comment: Perfecto, me funciona todo bien... el tema es que el botón no lo refresca y para que me salga el botón correcto tengo que refrescar. Estoy usando data-table

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el script se está ejecutando antes de cargar los botones en el DOM de la página, por lo que los eventos no se van a asignar a los botones. Seguramente en la consola de tu navegador debería salirte algún un error al respecto.

Una posible solución es añadir el script en un evento "window.onload", que retrasará la ejecución del script hasta que no se haya terminado de cargar el DOM de la página.

Te dejo un enlace con un ejemplo:
[Uso de window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Espero que te sea de ayuda.